Are there any DB dataset, free-to-use with no licenses whatsoever? I need to stress test a DB library. Fake or real data does not matter
I'm writing a library related to a specific DBMS. I fully wrote the code, unit and integration testing. 100% coverage already acheived and behavioural tests already cover all use cases.
I'm in the process of finilizning the doc, but I'd like to add some more test that use real data (or at least mimics real data), mainly for stress testing purposes and robustness.
My main concern is about licenses. I still do not know if I will try to sell it or make this software opensource... Either way I would like to have no legal issues whatsoever. Is there a free source of fake/real data? Or, if paid, not an arm and a leg.
